# Rspec test for controller with cancancan and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, factory-bot, rspec-rails, cancancan

I have used cancancan and devise for authorization and authentication. I have a role table and users table have role_id. I need help to write test with spec and factory girls. At the moment I get

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:blood_types)).to eq([blood_type])
```

I know I have to fix the role in factory girls. So user should have a role, but I don't know how.

```
class BloodTypesController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_user!
    load_and_authorize_resource
```

spec/support/controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user= FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  first_name Faker::Name.first_name
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password "password"
  password_confirmation "password"
  confirmed_at Date.yesterday
  end
end
```

spec/factories/blood_types.rb

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :blood_type do
    name "AB"

    end
end
```

spec/controllers/blood_types_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe BloodTypesController, type: :controller do
  let(:valid_attributes) {
      FactoryGirl.build(:blood_type).attributes
  }

  let(:valid_session) { {} }
  describe "GET #index" do
    login_user
    it "assigns all blood_types as @blood_types" do
      blood_type = BloodType.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:blood_types)).to eq([blood_type])
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a factory for `BloodType` as you created for `User`.

Then change: `BloodType.create! valid_attributes` to `FactoryGirl.create(:blood_type)`

Comment: I had blood_type factory. Just updated my question including that and also the valid_attributes. I tried what you suggested changing  `BloodType.create! valid_attributes` to `FactoryGirl.create(:blood_type)` did not help.

Comment: Check whether it enters into the `index` method and try to see the response status for the `index` method by using `expect(response).to be_success`